# Xcode 6 Code Sense stops working after build

Tags: ios, xcode6, codesense, symbol-not-found

So this same problem exists for a long time apparently. I checked all the xcode 4 code sense problems and used their solution and it works. Right up untill I build the file to run and then code sense stops working. I Really dont want to keep deleting the file in organizer and restarting xcode everytime. Is there a simpler method to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I always do when I lose Code Sense is to clean the project. If that doesn't work I use [Watchdog](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watchdog-for-xcode/id734258109?mt=12) to clean it. Watchdog deletes the derived data for the project like you can do in Organizer but it allows you to set up a handy keyboard shortcut which saves a ton of time now that Organizer doesn't have a keyboard shortcut.